# Описание предметной области ООП в MVC

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Начинаю погружаться в мир ООП. Читаю книжку PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования., дошел до главы с паттернами, начал разбираться с основными принципами ООП. Также параллельно коснулся темы MVC.

Возник вопрос - как проектировать предметную область в разрезе MVC? Описание предметной области и бизнес-логика должна находится в модели? А если в более прикладном смысле посмотреть на этот вопрос, например в рамках фреймворка Laravel. Я должен наследовать свои супер-классы от класса Model? А как тогда описать интерфейсы, абстрактные классы? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, желательно на примере Laravel.

Comment: Модель в Laravel скорее всего подразумевает только обертку над базой данных. Обустройство Domain Model оставляется на откуп самому программисту.

Comment: Описание предметной области - это отдельная тема. И по этой теме в основном одно словоблудие и никакой конкретики.